# Statistics books for someone who has a conceptual base in introductory statistics but little programming background in R

Tags: r, regression, anova, pattern-recognition

**Background**:

The most recent statistics class I've taken in university goes over topics such as experimental design, tests for Normality, comparing two samples, categorical data analysis, linear regression, MLR, and power analysis. As a result, I am working towards a conceptual base in these topics.

**Question**:

Are there any books that use R to reinforce these concepts and build on them towards advanced statistics such as advanced pattern recognition, if so which ones?

Comment: Max Kuhn developed the 'caret' package in R. His book *Applied Predictive Modeling* is an excellent introduction to the topics as well as R.

Answer (score 3):

It is a tall order to get a book that reviews basic statistics, introduces R, and takes you down the path to "advanced pattern recognition." I think that is a lot for one book. :-)

One of the best books on intermediate statistics in R, with discussions of both the statistics (and math) and R is Maindonald and Braun **Data Analysis and Graphics Using R: An Example-Based Approach**. If you have a good grounding in the topics you listed, this may be an excellent place to start. If your statistics are weaker that may be too much.

For pattern recognition and machine learning the book by James, Witten, Hastie, and Tibshirani, **An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R** probably is exactly what you want to consolidate the topics you listed in R and move toward machine learning. It is very elementary.

If you are better prepared, Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman's **The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction** is considered by many to be the bible of statistical machine learning. Both of these books are available from the authors for free as downloads from their websites.

Sorry, I am not up on really basic books that cover stats and R. But it is likely this questions will be closed as inappropriate soon (it is an opinion question and this site strives to avoid these), so good luck!

Answer (score 2):

These books have a lot of examples that cover basic topics as well as more advanced techniques used in machine learning.

- Statistics and Data with R: An Applied Approach Through Examples by
  Yosef Cohen, Jeremiah Y. Cohen
- Data Mining and Business Analytics with R by Johannes Ledolter
- R and Data Mining: Examples and Case Studies by Yanchang Zhao

Answer (score 2):

you may want to check this website, which lists books on R categorised into topics e.g. statistics, machine learning, data science, finance (it also shows required level of statistic and programming knowledge for each book):
https://www.rbookshub.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

There's an awesome guy on YouTube who does quick 2 minute videos on R programming to learn the basics very fast. I've learned so much from [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjKVrY7RptY36OdiuROb8QJs7gTFcVXhr), I can really recommend watching that. You'll have a fast introduction on what you can do with R.